# Dynamic linq expression tree with nested properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-expressions, expressionbuilder

I have a list which I must filter on child properties. The filter operator is dynamic and I'm using a predicate builder in order to combine several filters/lambdas.

For simplicity, let's say that I have two classes like this:

```
public class FirstClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SecondClass> MyList { get; set; }
}

public class SecondClass
{
    public int ReferenceId { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

My filter use a reference id, an operator type and a value, such that a pseudo code would be like this:

```
"list of FirstClass".Where(param1 => 
    param1.MyList.Single(param2 => 
        param2.ReferenceId == "reference id").Value "operatorType" "value")
```

The actual filter will be something like `123 eq 456`, where the reference id is 123, operatorType is "eq" and value is 456.

If the operator just was equality, then the following works just fine:

```
Expression<Func<FirstClass, bool>> lambda = 
    param1 => param1.MyList.Single(param2 => param2.ReferenceId == id).Value == value;
```

Also, filtering only on `FirstClass` with dynamic expressions, works like a charm, e.g. filtering on Id (my ExpressionTypeDictionary is a dictionary for selecting an `ExpressionType` based on the provided `operatorType`):

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(FirstClass), "param1");
Expression body = parameter;
body = Expression.Property(body, "Id");
body = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionTypeDictionary[operatorType], body, value);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<FirstClass, bool>>(body, new[] { parameter });
```

I'm able to get the following to compile, but executing the filter on real data using EF Core returns an exception for querySource:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(FirstClass), "param1");
Expression<Func<FirstClass, int>> left = param1 => 
    param1.MyClass.Single(param2 => param2.ReferenceId == id).Value;
var body = Expression.MakeBinary(
    ExpressionTypeDictionary[operatorType], 
    left.Body, 
    Expression.Constant(value));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<FirstClass, bool>>(body, new[] { parameter });
...
theList.Where(lambda);
```

Any suggestions are appreciated :)

Comment: you can use Gridify library.
https://github.com/alirezanet/gridify

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think rather than expression like this

```
Expression<Func<FirstClass, bool>> predicate = 
    x => x.MyList.Single(y => y.ReferenceId == id).Value [operator] value;
```

you'd better build an expression like this:

```
Expression<Func<FirstClass, bool>> predicate = 
    x => x.MyList.Any(y => y.ReferenceId == id && y.Value == value);
```

Here is how you can do that:

```
var innerParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SecondClass), "y");
var innerPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<SecondClass, bool>>(
    Expression.AndAlso(
        Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(innerParameter, "ReferenceId"), Expression.Constant(id)),
        Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionTypeDictionary[operatorType], Expression.Property(innerParameter, "Value"), Expression.Constant(value))),
    innerParameter);
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(FirstClass), "x");
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<FirstClass, bool>>(
    Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new Type[] { typeof(SecondClass) },
        Expression.Property(parameter, "MyList"), innerPredicate),
    parameter);
```

Comment: Your suggestion got me one step further, but I guess there's a bug in EF Core (I'm using version 1.0.0) that cause `Expression.And` to translate into `&` in the SQL query. By using `Expression.AndAlso` instead, the SQL syntax was fine and everything works as expected.

Comment: Oops, sorry, it should be `AndAlso`, I always mess them up :)